# prove $p (\bigcup A_i) \leq \sum p (A_i) $

Tags: probability-theory

Prove $p (\bigcup A_i) \leq \sum p (A_i) $

Now i doubt that this has not been proven already as it is a common question, but i am typing latex on my tablet because i spilled water on my computer so i am having trouble finding the question in the archives. if somebody could post a link. Thanks.  In case it has not been proven, i am thinking of using induction, but it just doesnt feel like the right thing to do to prove this question.

Comment: This is known as [Boole's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boole%27s_inequality) or the union bound.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the proofs based on set operations, there is another way with the help of the indicator function.
Let $1_A(x)$ be the indicator function, that is, $1_A(x) = 1$ on $x \in A$ and $0$ on $A^c$. We see that $P(A) = E(1_A(X))$. Obviously, 
$$ 1_{\cup_n A_n}(x) \leq \sum_n 1_{A_n}(x)$$
Taking expectation on both sides, each term on the right side in the sum is $ \geq 0 $ so we can interchange the sum and taking expectation, which  completes the proof.